# How to save Foreign Key OneToMany Relationship in Symfony 5 with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

I am new to Symfony and I have a problem with saving a foreign key in the table. I try to explain it as well as possible.

I am making a ToDo application.
- Every user has one profile
- Every profile has many items
- Any User can add new items to the list
- When the user creates a new item, the profile_id should be saved in the Item Table. But I get an Error. I have tried diferent ways to solve that but I can not find a soloution. I hope you can help me with that.

This is my Profile Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProfileRepository")
 */
class Profile
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $initials;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $postalCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $houseNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $houseNumberAddition;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phoneNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $mobileNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $accepted;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $visible;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Items", mappedBy="profile")
     */
    private $items;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGender(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    public function setGender(string $gender): self
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInitials(): ?string
    {
        return $this->initials;
    }

    public function setInitials(string $initials): self
    {
        $this->initials = $initials;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(string $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostalCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postalCode;
    }

    public function setPostalCode(string $postalCode): self
    {
        $this->postalCode = $postalCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setStreet(string $street): self
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHouseNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->houseNumber;
    }

    public function setHouseNumber(string $houseNumber): self
    {
        $this->houseNumber = $houseNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHouseNumberAddition(): ?string
    {
        return $this->houseNumberAddition;
    }

    public function setHouseNumberAddition(?string $houseNumberAddition): self
    {
        $this->houseNumberAddition = $houseNumberAddition;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phoneNumber;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(?string $phoneNumber): self
    {
        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobileNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mobileNumber;
    }

    public function setMobileNumber(?string $mobileNumber): self
    {
        $this->mobileNumber = $mobileNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccepted(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->accepted;
    }

    public function setAccepted(bool $accepted): self
    {
        $this->accepted = $accepted;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVisible(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->visible;
    }

    public function setVisible(bool $visible): self
    {
        $this->visible = $visible;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $createdAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface|null $updatedAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(?DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Items[]
     */
    public function getItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function addItem(Items $item): self
    {
        if (!$this->items->contains($item)) {
            $this->items[] = $item;
            $item->setProfile($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeItem(Items $item): self
    {
        if ($this->items->contains($item)) {
            $this->items->removeElement($item);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($item->getProfile() === $this) {
                $item->setProfile(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is my Item Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ItemsRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Items
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Profile", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $profile;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var datetime $createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updatedAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return Items
     */
    public function setId(int $id): Items
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProfile(): ?Profile
    {
        return $this->profile;
    }

    public function setProfile(?Profile $profile): self
    {
        $this->profile = $profile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return Items
     */
    public function setTitle(string $title): Items
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     * @return Items
     */
    public function setDescription(string $description): Items
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Items
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(DateTime $createdAt): Items
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Items
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTime $updatedAt): Items
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime("now");
    }
}
```

This is my Item Controller where a new Item gets stored

```
  /**
     * @Route("/item/create", name="create_item")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CreateTodoFormType::class, null, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('store_item')]);

        return $this->render('item/create.html.twig', [
            'todoForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/item/store", name="store_item", methods={"POST"})
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CreateTodoFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();

            $profile = $em->getRepository(Profile::class)->findBy(['user' => $this->getUser()->getId()]);

            $item = new Items();
            $item->setTitle($data->getTitle());
            $item->setDescription($data->getDescription());
            $item->setProfile($profile);

            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('item');
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('create_item', [
            'todoForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

When I do it in this way, I get an error!

**Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Items::setProfile() must be an instance of App\Entity\Profile or null, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\SymfonyProjects\symfony_to_do\src\Controller\ItemController.php on line 79**

Comment: just a hint - try to use the make:entity command. it is a great help with relations

Comment: When you define `$profile`, use `findOneBy()` instead of `findBy()`.

Comment: @ehymel
Thanks!!! I used findOneBy and it works great!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$profile = $em->getRepository(Profile::class)->findBy(['user' => $this->getUser()->getId()]);
```

This request returns an array, even if it contain just one element. You can use $profile[0] for the first element or better: use the findOneBy method!